# Pyspark: compare values and if true execute statement

Tags: loops, if-statement, pyspark, comparison

I am trying to make this loop work, where I compare the value of a approx_count_distinct to a threshold. I would like to execute the if statement when the distinct_count is <2.
but it always returns "NULL", even though when I print approx I get the right results (that are smaller than 2). What am I doing wrong?

```
for col in s:
    approx = df.agg(approx_count_distinct(col).alias("count"))
    if approx.collect()[0] < 2:
        print(col)
```

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/). What is your end goal? In any case, calling `collect()` is expensive, so you're better off calling it once rather than repeatedly in a loop. Perhaps what you really want is: `column_to_distinct_count_dict = next((row.asDict() for row in df.agg(*[approxCountDistinct(c).alias(c) for c in df.columns]).collect()), {})`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I ended up doing it this way:

```
for col in s:
    approx = df.agg(approx_count_distinct(col).alias("count"))
    if (approx.select(F.col("count")).rdd.flatMap(lambda x: x).collect()[0]) < 2:
        print(col)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are performing IF condition on ROW type,Can you please check what is the type of approx.collect()[0], it should be int to support the if condition you are performing.

```
type(approx.collect()[0])
```

You need to change it to `**if approx.collect()[0][0] < 2:`**

Try this, it should work:

```
s = ['a','b','c','d','e']

for col in s:
    approx = spark.sql("select 1 AS a")
    if approx.collect()[0][0] < 2:
        print(col)
```